# GZip existing varbinary(max) column in Sql Server 2008+

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, compression, varbinary

I have an existing legacy table that is ~180GB in size due to a client application storing PDF files as varbinary.  I'd like to be able to compress that column for all rows using GZIP to help save space while I create a new solution (I was hoping there was a way to do it in SQL and not have to write client code for this).  I see that the `COMPRESS` method is available for Sql Server 2016 but I need a solution that will work with 2008.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Although row/page compression is available in SQL 2008 R2, it does not compress LOB types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .NETs `GZipStream Class` with SQLCLR to do the compression since you are on SQL Server 2008.

Solomon Rutzky has a free SQLCLR version ([Util_GZip and Util_GUnzip functions](https://sqlsharp.com/features/?ref=db_212233)) that you can test and use.

See : [Alternative way to compress NVARCHAR(MAX)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135701/8783)

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Dude youre the man!